# RSS feeds articles not showing in mozilla firefox only

Tags: firefox, rss, rss2

I followed the following tutorial to create a RSS FEED:

```
http://ci-codeigniter.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-build-rss-20-feed-with.html
```

Everything is good in all browsers except mozilla firefox.

```
http://lowcostseo.co/feeds
```

is the feed.

Im not sure what went wrong. Does anyone knows whats wrong with Firefox?

Thanks. 
-------------EDITS------------------------

Whats Happening: 
If you check http://lowcostseo.co/feeds in chrome all is good i think but if you check it on  mozilla you'll find that there no articles showing but if you check the the source code there are articles. So basically firefox is not showing articles which is present in source code.

Whats Expected: 
The articles needs to be shown in firefox RSS FEED at http://lowcostseo.co/feeds

Comment: You may want to explain what's happening vs. what you expected to happen in Firefox. The more info you give us the better your odds of a good answer.

Comment: @computerfreaker please check the edits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your feed is not valid, so you should not really expect any reader to do a consistent good job at displaying it.

The most obvious problem is that you do not close `<link>` element in your `<item>` elements... 
You should really [check the validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://lowcostseo.co/feeds) and make sure your feed is valid before anything else.